# Stop chromium/html2image from sending error messages

Tags: chromium

I am using chromium to take screenshots of html pages with the `html2image` python library, and it keeps printing messages such as:

```
[0216/152304.453205:ERROR:xattr.cc(63)] setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file /var/folders/4p/b_3ktmw102x1zrc3vry_sv3c0000gn/T/: Operation not permitted (1)
[0216/152304.461573:ERROR:file_io.cc(94)] ReadExactly: expected 8, observed 0
[0216/152304.466293:ERROR:xattr.cc(63)] setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file /var/folders/4p/b_3ktmw102x1zrc3vry_sv3c0000gn/T/: Operation not permitted (1)
[0216/152306.112644:INFO:headless_shell.cc(659)] Written to file /Users/riccardosartori/pycharm-workspace/reditor/data/tmp/download-selfposts/c7H2lgki5k.png.
[0216/152306.121950:ERROR:node_controller.cc(585)] Trying to re-add dropped peer 89F8B9AC473DFBF.94C81A0A00FAF64F
```

[The module](https://github.com/vgalin/html2image/blob/d4cde546db299f5637c860a842c0944d2b3699b2/html2image/browsers/chrome.py#L205) uses the chromium command line with the `--screenshot` argument to take the screenshot, and I can set custom flags. I've tried adding the flags `--log-level=OFF` and `--log-level=3`, but none of these seem to stop these messages. Is there any other flag I'm missing that could disable these?

I could redirect stdout and stderr in the subprocess call to `subprocess.DEVNULL`, but I would like to find a solution without modifying the module, if possible.

Comment: This issue will be addressed in a later release of the package, see https://github.com/vgalin/html2image/issues/55